# how can I initialize an object in typescript dynamically from an array and a map function?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Lets consider the interface `I`:

```
interface I {
    [k: string]: number;
}
```

It is easy to initialize an object of type `I`:

```
const obj: I = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2
}
```

To initialize an object dynamically from an array `array` and and a mapping function `func` I have to write:

```
const o2: I = {};
for (const att of array) {
    o2[att] = func (att);
}
```

Now I have to write the type annotation for `I`.

Is there a possibility to initialize the object in one statement?

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the object with this function:

```
function objectMap<T> (array: string[],
                       func: (key: string) => T): Record<string, T> {
    return Object.fromEntries (array.map (element => {
        // this annotation is necessary
        const kv: [string, T] = [element, func (element)];
        return kv;
    }))
}
```

now you can write:

```
const obj = objectMap (array, func);
```

and typescript recognises `obj` as type `Record<string, number>`

There is also an asynchronous version:

```
async function objectMapAsync<T> (array: string[],
                                  func: (key: string) => Promise<T>)
    : Promise<Record<string, T>> {
    return Object.fromEntries (await Promise.all (array.map (async element => {
        const kv: [string, T] = [element, await func (element)];
        return kv;
    })));
}

const obj = await objectMapAsync (array, func);
```

This works since es2019